# Issue with options in lightning-select from js

Tags: javascript-debugging, lightningselect

I am learning to build some basic lwc and I am struggling with dynamically putting lightning-select options from JS.

Here's the html:

```
<lightning-select
                name="distribution-method"
                label="Distribution method"
                value={distributionValue}
                options={distributionMethod}
                onchange={handleDistributionChange}>
</lightning-select>
```

Here's the apex code:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<String> getPickListValueDuringOnLoad(String objectName,String fieldName){
    List<String> picklistValues = new List<String>();
    Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobjectDescribe = sobjectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = sobjectDescribe.fields.getMap();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistEntries = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : picklistEntries) {
        picklistValues.add(picklistEntry.getValue());
    }
    return picklistValues;
}
```

This works great as I can see it in console.log from JS.

And here's the JS:

```
@track distributionOptions;
@track distributionMethod = '';
@track opportunityLineItem = '';
@track distributionValue = '';

@wire(getPickListValueDuringOnLoad, 
{objectName:'OpportunityLineItem',fieldName:'Distribution_method__c'})
wiredPickListValues({data, error}){
    if (data) {
        console.log('@@@@@'+data);
        this.distributionMethod = data.map(item => {
            return { label: item, value: item };
        });
    } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

So what should I change in the JS for those options to be visible?

Curenntly the results is:
[image]

Comment: What's the output of the `console.log()`?

Comment: @@@@@EXW,FCA,FAS

Proxy(Array) {}

{InstrumentationResult :  ( RECEIVED = 11 , SUCCESS -> LOG = 11 , Topic = AILTN )  , TracingResponse : ( AsyncResults ) , TelemetryResponse : ( AsyncResults )O11yInstrumentationResult : O11y Logs successfully processed by instrumentation-processing: {…}}


Those are the last three things that pop up, first being the list of options I get from Apex into data variable.

Comment: Try it that way: `console.log('@@@@@'+JSON.stringify(data));`, that should give you a more helpful output, showing the exact json response that you got from apex.

Answer (score 0):

The platform provides ready made server-side code for most of this: see [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values.html).

Note that picklist values have both a label and a value. Often these are the same but they can be different so you should preserve them in your logic. The [lightning-combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example) (there is no `lightning-select` AFAIK) `options` property requires an array of options where each option have a `value` and `label` property - see the code in the "Example" tab.

Comment: I don't know whether you check my code but I am trying to change the list from APEX into an array here:

return { label: item, value: item };

When it comes to lightning-select: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/example

Comment: Hi @MaciejZadworny, I'm advising you to use the standard pattern that passes both the value and label from the server-side to the client side rather than write your own code that only passes the value. Apologies about the `lightning-select` comment - my bad. Not sure what is wrong with your code; using `console.log('@@@@@'+JSON.stringify(data));` might help you debug. As might an Apex unit test of your server-side Apex code.

Comment: Keith, thanks! I will try it this way.